# How do I change this value using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that's structured as so:

```
"http://mydomain.com/?i=0"
```

I'd like to be able to change the value of `i` using a regular expression in javascript but I'm not sure how to do it. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Is the initial value always going to be numeric? If so, what's the possible range?

Comment: Also, if it will always be identical leading up to the value, it might be easier to work with substrings

Comment: And do you have control over what you use as the replacing variable? "i" is a really bad one, being very commonly used... a regex, for example, would very easily replace the "i" in "domain" as well as in your querystring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"http://mydomain.com/?i=0".replace(/i=.*$/, 'i='+<newValue>);
```

if you need to cater for additional parameters following `i` use

```
"http://mydomain.com/?i=0&j=k".replace(/i=[^&]+/, 'i='+<newValue>);
```

there is [a fiddle to demonstrate it](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/vwQyb/)

Comment: That regex will also replace any additional parameters passed in after the 'i' parameter.

Comment: This should work. Just wondering if it will ever be passed through as null (i.e. http://mydomain.com/?i&j=k)

Comment: @tro: `?i&j=k` is not a legal query string portion. you have a point, however, wrt `?i=&j=k` - using `*` instead of `+` in the regexp will do the trick.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done GET methods in PHP, apologies.

Comment: That's totally a legal query string.  What's allowed and what isn't in the query string is surprisingly open in the URI spec.  `a=b&c=d` is just a convention.

Comment: @MatthewGilliard: you're right, thank you - there always is something new to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a place to start:

```
str = "http://mydomain.com/?i=0";
str = str.replace(/((?:\?|&)i=)([^&]*)/g, '$1foo');
```

Comment: This will replace the `?` character as well.

Comment: You may also want to add `str = ` at the beginning, since the replace won't actually change the `str` value otherwise.   ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript replace() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

I'm not going to do the Regex for you as you have demonstrated no attempt at doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var str = "http://mydomain.com/?i=0";

var i=1; // or any other value (e.g. i="test")
str = str.replace(/i=.*/, 'i='+i);
alert(str);
```

Comment: The parameter may not always be numeric, the OP hasn't confirmed that.

Comment: Well, the examples states: `http://mydomain.com/?i=0`. seems pretty numeric to me.

Comment: That would have worked for the example, but not for a string if given one, nor for a floating-point number or negative integer, either of which may be likely until we know more about his situation.

Comment: ack, changed `\d+` to `.*`. Regex `/i=[^&]*/` is even better.